# Cancel http request

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-http

In jQuery ajax there's a way to abort ajax queries:

```
var xhr = $.ajax({ ... });
```

when user wants to abort the operation or navigates to other page in a single page app I can call

```
xhr.abort();
```

In angular2-http api I cannot find any possibility to abort the query as it uses rxjs.

Is there a way to abort the ajax query in angular2?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel a subscription in Angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442693/how-to-cancel-a-subscription-in-angular2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you subscribe, you get a subscription you can use to unsubscribe

```
this.httpSubscription = this.http.get(...).subscribe(...);
...
this.httpSubscription.unsubscribe();
```

Answer (score 1):

For a simple solution you can use the following, but you can also use .switchMap rxjs method..

```
if ( this.subscription ) {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
this.subscription = this.http.get( 'awesomeApi' )
 .subscribe((res)=> {
  // your awesome code..
})
```

Comment: what if the API calls are in a loop  this.http.get( 'awesomeApi' )
 .subscribe((res)=> {
  // your awesome code..
})

Comment: track of the last subscription (api call) .. if (special condition) { kill loop and unsubscripte last subscription } please provide more code if you need help