# Angular 4 is getting slower through time

Tags: angular, google-chrome, raspberry-pi

I have an angular 4.3.5 application that is getting slower after it is used for a while (~20 minutes).

**My scenario is like:**

- Rest API and static angular html/css/js running on RaspberryPi B 3
- ~30 RaspberryPI B 3 accessing static angular application through Chromium (versions 58 and 60)

**What occurs:**

- The Angular's HTTP requests got slower at time pass. Example: from ~100 ms to ~2 seconds

**Additional information:**

- If I press F5 on Chromium, the Angular application come back to normal
- Angular uses this template https://themeforest.net/item/primer-angular-2-material-design-admin-template/19228165
- Angular uses a Google Chrome/Chromium app, that I wrote, for communication with an Arduino through serial port (Chrome API: chrome.runtime.sendMessage, chrome.runtime.connect and chrome.serial)
- The client, RaspberryPi, has available resources (CPU and memory) when the application get slow
- Angular application stores almost nothing on the browser

The component that presents the problem is the following:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

import { SweetAlertService } from 'ng2-cli-sweetalert2';

import { ApiService } from '.././api.service';
import { NFCService } from '.././nfc.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.scss']
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private ngUnsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  cardId: string;
  userId: string;
  userName: string;
  is_secure_bar: boolean = false;

  requestInProgress = false;

  userBalance: number = 0;

  step: number = 1;
  // showCheckout: boolean = false;

  categories = new Array();
  subcategories = new Array();
  products = new Array();

  cartItems = new Array();

  countCartItems: number = 0;
  totalCartValue: number = 0;

  table_scroller;
  table_scroller_height;
  show_scroller_btns = false;

  constructor(
    public router: Router,
    public route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _nfcService: NFCService,
    private _apiService: ApiService,
    private _swal: SweetAlertService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    var account = localStorage.getItem('account');
    if (account) {
      // set variable to catch user data
      // JSON.parse(
    } else {
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    }

    this.route.params
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.cardId = params.id;
      this._apiService.getCardUser(params.id)
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          // SUCCESS
          this.userId = response.data[0].uuid;
          this.userBalance = response.data[0].balance;
          this.userName = response.data[0].name;
        },
        error => {
          // ERROR
          console.log('Failed ;(', error);
        }
      );
    });

    this.getEvents()
    .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
    .subscribe(
      response => {
        if (response.data[0].options.sales_auth_after_buy_is_required) {
          this.is_secure_bar = true;
        }
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Erro ao verificar Evento.')
      }
    );

    var categories = localStorage.getItem('cache_categories');
    if (categories) {
      this.categories = JSON.parse(categories);
    } else {
      // this.getCategories();
      this.getCategoriesP()
    }

  }

  //@felipe_todo
  getEvents()
  {
    return this._apiService.getEvents();

    //COMO FAZER LOGOUT ABAIXO
    //localStorage.clear();
  }

  getCategories() {
    this._apiService.getProductsCategories()
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      .subscribe(response => {
        // SUCCESS
        this.categories = response.data;
        localStorage.setItem('cache_categories', JSON.stringify(this.categories));
      }, error => {
        // ERROR
        console.log('Failed ;(', error);
      });
  }

  getCategoriesP() {
    let categories;
    this._apiService.getCategories()
      .then(response => categories = response)
      .then(() => {
        this.categories = categories;
        console.log(categories);
      });
  }

  categorySelected(item) {
    this.step = 2;

    var subcategories = localStorage.getItem('cache_subcategories_' + item.uuid);
    if (subcategories) {
      this.subcategories = JSON.parse(subcategories);
    } else {
      // this.getSubcategories(item.uuid);
      this.getSubcategoriesP(item.uuid);
    }
  }

  getSubcategories(uuid) {
    this._apiService.getProductsSubcategories(uuid)
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      .subscribe(response => {
        // SUCCESS
        this.subcategories = response.data;
        localStorage.setItem('cache_subcategories_' + uuid, JSON.stringify(this.subcategories));
      }, error => {
        // ERROR
        console.log('Failed ;(', error);
      });
  }

  getSubcategoriesP(uuid) {
    let subcategories;
    this._apiService.getSubcategories(uuid)
      .then(response => subcategories = response)
      .then(() => {
        this.subcategories = subcategories;
        console.log(subcategories);
      });
  }

  subCategorySelected(item) {
    this.step = 3;

    var products = localStorage.getItem('cache_products_' + item.uuid);
    if (products) {
      this.products = JSON.parse(products);
    } else {
      // this.getProducts(item.uuid);
      this.getProductsP(item.uuid);
    }
  }

  getProducts(uuid) {
    this._apiService.getProducts(uuid)
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      .subscribe(response => {
        // SUCCESS
        this.products = response.data;
        localStorage.setItem('cache_products_' + uuid, JSON.stringify(this.products));
      }, error => {
        // ERROR
        console.log('Failed ;(', error);
      });
  }

  getProductsP(uuid) {
    let products;
    this._apiService.getProductList(uuid)
      .then(response => products = response)
      .then(() => {
        this.products = products;
        console.log(products);
      });
  }

  addToCard(product) {
    var existentItems = this.cartItems.filter(function(item) {
      return item.uuid === product.uuid
    });

    if (existentItems.length) {
      existentItems[0].quantity += 1
    } else {
      product.quantity = 1;
      this.cartItems.unshift(product);
    }
    let that = this;
    this.calculateTotal();
    setTimeout(function(){
      that.setScroller();
    }, 300);
  }

  removeProduct(index) {
    let product = this.cartItems[index]
    var existentItems = this.cartItems.filter(function(item) {
      return item.uuid === product.uuid
    });

    if (existentItems.length) {
      existentItems[0].quantity -= 1
      if (existentItems[0].quantity == 0) {
        this.cartItems.splice(index, 1);
      }
    } else {
      product.quantity = 1;
      this.cartItems.splice(index, 1);
    }

    this.calculateTotal();
    let that = this;
    setTimeout(function(){
      if (that.table_scroller.offsetHeight < 270) {
        that.show_scroller_btns = false;
      }
    }, 300);
  }

  calculateTotal() {
    this.countCartItems = 0;
    this.totalCartValue = 0;

    var that = this;
    this.cartItems.forEach(function(item) {
      that.countCartItems += item.quantity;
      that.totalCartValue += item.value * item.quantity;
    });
  }

  backStep() {
    if (this.step == 2) {
      this.subcategories = new Array();
    } else if (this.step == 3) {
      this.products = new Array();
    }

    this.step--;
  }

  setScroller() {
    if (this.cartItems.length) {
      if (!this.table_scroller) {
        this.table_scroller = document.querySelector('#table-scroller');
      }else {
        console.log(this.table_scroller.offsetHeight)
        if (this.table_scroller.offsetHeight >= 270) {
          this.show_scroller_btns = true;
        } else {
          this.show_scroller_btns = false;
        }
      }
    }
  }

  scrollDown() {
    (<HTMLElement>this.table_scroller).scrollTop = (<HTMLElement>this.table_scroller).scrollTop+50;
  }

  scrollUp() {
    (<HTMLElement>this.table_scroller).scrollTop = (<HTMLElement>this.table_scroller).scrollTop-50;
  }

  confirmDebit() {

    if (this.requestInProgress) return;

    if (this.userBalance < this.totalCartValue) {
      this._swal.error({ title: 'Salto Insuficiente', text: 'Este cliente não possui saldo suficiente para essa operação.' });
      return;
    }

    this.requestInProgress = true;

    var order = {
      card_uuid: this.cardId,
      event_uuid: 'c7b5bd69-c2b5-4226-b043-ccbf91be0ba8',
      products: this.cartItems
    };

    let is_secure_bar = this.is_secure_bar;

    this._apiService.postOrder(order)
       .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
         .subscribe(response => {
        console.log('Success');
        // this.router.navigate(['customer', this.userId]);

        let that = this;
        this._swal.success({
          title: 'Debito Efetuado',
          text: 'O débito foi efetuado com sucesso',
          showCancelButton: false,
          confirmButtonText: 'OK',
          allowOutsideClick: false,
        }).then(function(success) {
          console.log("Clicked confirm");
          if (is_secure_bar) {
            that.logout();
          } else {
            that.router.navigate(['card']);
          }
        });

        this.requestInProgress = false;

      }, error => {
        // ERROR
        console.log('Request Failed ;(', error);

        if (error.status !== 0) {
          // TODO: Should display error message if available!
          this._swal.error({ title: 'Erro', text: 'Ocorreu um erro inesperado ao conectar-se ao servidor de acesso.' });
        } else {
          this._swal.error({ title: 'Erro', text: 'Não foi possível conectar-se ao servidor de acesso. Por favor verifique sua conexão.' });
        }

        this.requestInProgress = false;
      }
      );
  }

  logout() {
    let that = this;
    localStorage.clear();
    that.router.navigate(['login']);
  }

  clearCheckout() {
    this.cartItems = new Array();
    this.calculateTotal();

    this.router.navigate(['card']);
  }

    ngOnDestroy() {
      console.log('uhul')
        this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
        this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
    }

}
```

The methods that present slowness each time we access the component are:

getCategories()
getSubcategories(uuid)
getProducts(uuid)
confirmDebit()

For testing purposes we have created a new version for each of these methods, this time working with promises:

getCategoriesP()
getSubcategoriesP(uuid)
getProductsP(uuid)

Regardless of the version of the called method, the same problem occurs.

Comment: Certainly sounds like a memory leak, how are you calling the API on repeat?

Comment: I agree, look at any loops you may be doing and or code for calling data continuously. Would we be able to see code as well?

Comment: I have edited the question with the component code that presents the problem. I hope it helps. Thank you.

Comment: I am now looking at EventEmitter and Observable. I plan to replace EventEmitter to Observable and unsubscribe all of them when my component is destroyed, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274637/4668660

Comment: dude how much shit is that component responsible for?

Comment: I'd move as much logic as possible into services. Seeing as services are singletons, you'll probably have less memory leaks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you are running your application as an SPA (Single Page Application), then this may be one of the causes for the performance degradation as time elapses.

In SPA, **the DOM gets heavier every time the user visits a new page**. Hence you have to work on how to keep the DOM lightweight.

Below are the main reasons which I found significantly improved my application's  performance.

**Check below points:**

- If you have used tab control then load only active tab content and other tab content should not exist on the DOM.
- If any popup is going to load make sure it loads the body only when it opens.
- Common components like `confirmation popup` and `message alert` should be defined once and globally accessible.
- *ngFor apply with trackby (https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5)

**After the service finishes, call destroy on any objects:** (below is the example of calling a service)

```
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/takeUntil';

ngOnDestroy() {        
    this.ngUnsubscribe.next(true);
    this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
}

this.frameworkService.ExecuteDataSource().takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe).subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Refer below links for more details:

https://medium.com/paramsingh-66174/catalysing-your-angular-4-app-performance-9211979075f6

Comment: Might as well save the subscription and then unsubscribe in ngOnDestroy.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies somewhere within that subscription mechanism in your get-Methods

> (getProducts, getCategories etc.)

How do you create that observable that is returned from the calls to your api-Service? After you call your api-Service you subscribe on the return-value of that call. Is that the original response from the http-request? Or is it an oeservable that you created yourself?

In general, you do not need to call unsubscribe on http-calls in angular, as is described here:

[Do you need to unsubscribe from Angular 2 http calls to prevent memory leak?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35042929/do-you-need-to-unsubscribe-from-angular-2-http-calls-to-prevent-memory-leak)

But in case you not passing through that original http-observable, but instead creating your own abservable, then you might need to clean it up yourself.

Maybe you can post some code of your api-Service? How do you create those promises?

**Another Thing**: 
Are you calling you getProducts-Method with a different uuid every time? You would be writing a new entry into localStorage with every single uuid that you call that method with

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether this will solve your performance problem, but it could be a step in the right direction.

You are creating a new Subscription each time a route param changes, so potentially you could end up with a lot of subscriptions:

```
this.route.params
.takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
.subscribe(params => {
  this.cardId = params.id;
  this._apiService.getCardUser(params.id)
  .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
  .subscribe(
    response => {
      // SUCCESS
      this.userId = response.data[0].uuid;
      this.userBalance = response.data[0].balance;
      this.userName = response.data[0].name;
    },
    error => {
      // ERROR
      console.log('Failed ;(', error);
    }
  );
});
```

I think you'd better use switchMap, that way there will only be 1 subscription. Something like:

`this.route.params
    .switchMap(params => {
      this.cardId = params.id;
      return this._apiService.getCardUser(params.id)
     })
      .takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
      .subscribe(
        response => {
          // SUCCESS
          this.userId = response.data[0].uuid;
          this.userBalance = response.data[0].balance;
          this.userName = response.data[0].name;
        },
        error => {
          // ERROR
          console.log('Failed ;(', error);
        }
      );
    });`