# Why subscription survives after component destroyed?

Tags: angular, rxjs

My Angular application has many components, one is MyComponent and the component class of which is shown bellow:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/interval';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my',
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  a = 'I still alive';
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(x => console.log(this.a));
  }
}
```

If I visit to MyComponent, the subscription starts as expected. Say, I now navigate away from MyComponent and MyComponent should now be destroyed. But still I can see the subscription survives (the console logs keeps on coming). What are the practical benifit of allowing subscription to survive after the host component (MyComponent) has been destroyed?

(If I want to unsubscribe, I can do it in the ngOnDestroy() method of MyComponent, but how to unsubscribe is not the point of discussion here)

Comment: Because the subscription is independent from the component, this is why unsubscribe exists

Comment: The subscription is independent from the component, this is why unsubscribe exists, yes this is obvious. But, how this works? Where subscription is kept? Why it is kept while component is destroyed?

Comment: It's kept in memory, hence the name memory leak.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442693/how-to-cancel-a-subscription-in-angular2

Comment: Subscription is like a separate and independent thread. It is not dependent on component. Component only have a reference. You can destroy only using    ngOnDestroy() {  this.subscription.unsubscribe(); }

Answer (score 0):

After I made some research on this topic, I found out that I need not unsubscribe some of my subscriptions that Angular manages, for example subscriptions made on `ActivatedRoute`. This is what the [official guide](https://angular.io/guide/router) says:

> When subscribing to an observable in a component, you almost always
>   arrange to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed.
>
> There are a few exceptional observables where this is not necessary.
>   The ActivatedRoute observables are among the exceptions.
>
> The ActivatedRoute and its observables are insulated from the Router
>   itself. The Router destroys a routed component when it is no longer
>   needed and the injected ActivatedRoute dies with it.
>
> Feel free to unsubscribe anyway. It is harmless and never a bad
>   practice.

In the case where I have to unsubscribe, an effective [generalized approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38008334/angular-rxjs-when-should-i-unsubscribe-from-subscription) is recommended.

Answer (score -1):

The `observable` is a concept of RxJS, independent of `Angular` lifecycle.

As of now, the `stream of data`, which you subscribes to, are subscribed and monitored independent of Angular lifecycle. So, even when the `component` is destroyed, the memory keeps the reference and so we get memory leak.

So, we need to explicitly tell the `RxJS` to remove that reference by `unsubscribing` the `observable` in `destroy` phase.