# How to unsubscribe timer in angular 6?

Tags: angular

I am facing problem while working with timer in angular 6. I am not able to unsubscribe timer after certain meet condition.

```
this.testInterval=interval(1000).pipe(
      map(x => this.testSecTime )
    ).subscribe(x => this.reduceTimer());
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/34442693/5468463

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cancel a subscription in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34442693/how-to-cancel-a-subscription-in-angular2)

Answer (score 2):

use `unsubscribe` for this.

> if page destoy

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.testInterval.unsubscribe()
}
```

OR

> for any condition

```
this.testInterval.unsubscribe()
```

Answer (score 1):

use `unsubscribe`

```
this.testInterval.unsubscribe()
```