# IONIC 5: Issues in changing Events to Observable

Tags: javascript, angular, events, observable, ionic5

Since Ionic 5 came out I decided to try it out.
I have learned that they are now using Oberservables instead of Events. 
I have the following event in my code:

Subscribing like this in my constructor:

```
                this.events.subscribe('go-to-slide', (tab, id) => {
  this.currentID = id;
  if (id === 0) {
    this.showLeftButton = false;
  }
  // if data has already been loaded
  if (this.dataLoadedFlag === true) {
    // from tile
    if (this.globalVariableService.comesFromTileClick === true) {
      if (this.globalVariableService.languageChanged === true) {
        this.languageChanged = false;
        this.slidesComponent.slides.slideTo(id, 0);
        this.getSectorTitlesAndColours();
        this.dataLoadedFlag = true;
        this.updateHeader(id);
      } else if (this.globalVariableService.languageChanged === false) {
        this.updateHeader(id);
      }
    } else if (this.globalVariableService.comesFromTileClick === false) {

    }
  } else if (this.dataLoadedFlag === false) {

    if (this.globalVariableService.comesFromTileClick === true) {
      this.slidesComponent.slides.slideTo(id, 0);
      this.getSectorTitlesAndColours();
      this.dataLoadedFlag = true;
      this.updateHeader(id);
    } else if (this.globalVariableService.comesFromTileClick === false) {
      this.getSectorTitlesAndColours();
      this.showRightButton = true;
      this.dataLoadedFlag = true;
      this.updateHeader(0);
    }
  }
  const tempGlobalVariableService = this.globalVariableService;
  // tslint:disable-next-line: only-arrow-functions
  setTimeout(function() {
    tempGlobalVariableService.comesFromTileClick = false;
  }, 500);
});
}
```

and publishing the event like this in different components/methods:

```
this.events.publish('go-to-slide', 1, 1);
```

I tried different ways to change this code to observable but I can't seem to find the right way.

Anyone tried this already and can help me out?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix member Event from @ionic/angular error in Ionic 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197785/how-to-fix-member-event-from-ionic-angular-error-in-ionic-5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have already answered it here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60246906/2405040

You can create a small service for that like:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GlobalFooService {

    private fooSubject = new Subject<any>();

    publishSomeData(data: any) {
        this.fooSubject.next(data);
    }

    getObservable(): Subject<any> {
        return this.fooSubject;
    }
}
```

For a complete example, please refer to the other answer.

And by the way, to discuss on this comment:

> I have learned that they are now using Oberservables instead of Events

This is not that true. Basically, they have removed the `Events` service from Ionic 5 and asking us to use the `Observables` instead, by creating our own similar implementation.

They might have been using the `Events` internally since Ionic 3. But since Ionic 4that, they have removed the internal usage as Obersables has grown so much and it's a kind of backbone to both Angular & Ionic.

Comment: Hi, I tried using what you suggested my only problem now is that in subscribing I need to pass to parameters (tab, id)  and i have changed the code to: publishGoToSlide(tab:any, id:any) {
this.GoToSlideObservable.next(tab);
this.GoToSlideObservable.next(id);}

And in subscribe it is not letting me pass two parameters as I did above... how can I go about it?

This is what im doing in my component to subscribe:

this.eventservice.goToSlideObserveble().subscribe((tab,id) => { // code here }

I am getting an error when passing the two parameters above

Comment: Never mind I know what i was doing wrong. Thank you :)