# ionic 5 / Angular show me cannot get

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I import old project but When I ionic serve to show me this ERROR  `Cannot GET /`

How to fix member Event from @ionic/angular error in Ionic 5

```
[ng] ERROR in src/app/account/login/login.page.ts:4:67 – error TS2305: Module ‘”C:/ftt/node_modules/@ionic/angular/ionic-angular”‘ has no exported member ‘Events’.
[ng] 4 import { ToastController,NavController,Platform,LoadingController,Events } from ‘@ionic/angular’;
[ng] ~~~~~~
[ng] src/app/app.component.ts:3:33 – error TS2305: Module ‘”C:/ftt/node_modules/@ionic/angular/ionic-angular”‘ has no exported member ‘Events’.
[ng] 3 import { Platform,NavController,Events } from ‘@ionic/angular’;
[ng] ~~~~~~
[ng] src/app/detail/detail.page.ts:3:61 – error TS2305: Module ‘”C:/ftt/node_modules/@ionic/angular/ionic-angular”‘ has no exported member ‘Events’.
[ng] 3 import { NavController,Platform,LoadingController,IonSlides,Events,AlertController,ToastController } from ‘@ionic/angular’;
[ng] ~~~~~~
[ng] src/app/home/home.page.ts:3:61 – error TS2305: Module ‘”C:/ftt/node_modules/@ionic/angular/ionic-angular”‘ has no exported member ‘Events’.
[ng] 3 import { NavController,Platform,LoadingController,IonSlides,Events,AlertController,ToastController } from ‘@ionic/angular’;
[ng] ~~~~~~
[ng] src/app/lang/lang.page.ts:3:67 – error TS2305: Module ‘”C:/ftt/node_modules/@ionic/angular/ionic-angular”‘ has no exported member ‘Events’.
[ng] 3 import { ToastController,Platform,LoadingController,NavController,Events } from ‘@ionic/angular’;
```

Comment: Did you run "npm install" ?

Comment: yes i run it  still error

Comment: try to remove the node module and package-lock.json and reinstall npm `npm install`.

Comment: i try  reinstall npm stll error

Comment: i see this https://medium.com/wizpanda/dealing-with-breaking-change-in-ionic-5-db3ba711dfcd    but don't understand exactly how

Answer (score 0):

Events are not longer supported in ionic 5. 
See this example, to introduce GlobalEventService
[How to fix member Event from @ionic/angular error in Ionic 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60197785/how-to-fix-member-event-from-ionic-angular-error-in-ionic-5)